# Rearranging Lemmas in Lean programming

Tags: algorithm, lean

The final step to a tutorial is to match both LHS and RHS since a*b is not the same as b*a according to the rules of the LEAN programing. The Goal is given below.

> Goal:
> a ^ d * b ^ d * a * b = a ^ d * a * b ^ d * b

Is there a faster way to swap `b ^ d * a` to match the RHS? With the invisible brackets the statement actually looks like: `((a ^ d * b ^ d) * a )* b`,

The long way to this is to massage the brackets to `(a ^ d * (b ^ d * a) * b)` before using`[mul_col]` and then repeated `[mul_assoc]` to push the brackets to match on both sides.

Comment: Try the tactics `ring`, or `ring_exp` or `abel` or `group`